# How to build working associations between models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm stuck while building my first Rails app.  I created two models and related controllers:  Exercise and Member.  In the respective models I coded several validations and an association between them:
  Member has_many exercises, and
  exercise belongs_to member.
My schema.db indicates my exercises table includes a column named "member_id" an integer.  The schema also contains the following line:
  add_index "exercises", ["member_id"], name: "index_exercises_on_member_id"
So far, my rspec tests are passing.

Here's where I'm stuck ...
My goal is to track exercises by specific members. However, when I go to create an exercise I don't see a way to designate which member is performing the exercise. Nothing on my forms or in my views indicate a connection between a member and an exercise. It's as if the two tables are not connected in anyway. What I'm I missing or doing wrong? Any help or hints to get me unstuck are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to build that part yourself. Most Rails tutorials discuss this problem.

Comment: Rails guides offers great exlainations on associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html.

Comment: Dave - when you say "you need to build that part yourself," what file or files should I be working on to get the desired connection between my models? Any hints?  I'm doing the Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl, but I'm not very far along (recently finished Chapter 4).